# SkMaps Android - How to get lat/lng used to draw roads

Tags: android, skmaps

I would like to use the lat/lng data used to draw roads to make my own custom routes and draw lines beside the streets (like to indicate sidewalks). Is there any functionality like `getPolyline("SanFran Road")` that will give me data points that I can use to draw my custom routes/lines?

Answer (score 0):

You have the [pointToCoordinate](http://developer.skobbler.ro/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html#pointToCoordinate(com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKScreenPoint)) that returns the long/lat position relative to the screen position.
See more in the [SKMapSurfaceView](http://developer.skobbler.ro/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html) class.